# Use custom, local domain for virtual machine in Firefox

Tags: firefox, virtual-machine, dns, domain, tld

I have set up my Windows development system with VMWare Workstation to host a Linux server on which I edit test sites.  I have assigned the domain "vm" to that virtual machine's IP address, so that any subdomain resolves to my virtual machine's servers.

The problem:  When I type only "project.vm" in Firefox, Firefox does not recognize the ".vm" as a TLD, and it forwards my submission to the default search engine.  Normally, I appreciate this feature, but what I would really like is to add ".vm" to the list of TLDs that Firefox ignores for searching, and just resolve the domain like it would a ".com".

Is there a setting in Firefox I can set that will let me use .vm domains for my virtual machine without entering "http://" in front, that still retains for all other submissions the ability to forward to my default search?

Answer (score 2):

- In the Firefox address bar, enter `about:config`
- Right-click, select **New -> Boolean**
- Enter `network.IDN.whitelist.vm` in the name and **true** for the value

this should make `.vm` a trusted TLD.

Comment: I guess this is used for something else, no? http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.IDN.whitelist.*

Comment: gotta tack on the trailing `.*` to snark's url, markdown broke it: `http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.IDN.whitelist.*`

Comment: (still a broken link but at least it's a little easier to spot...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox 3.0.x and can't replicate your issue.

I believe that Firefox first tries to resolve the text typed into the location bar.  If the resolver fails, that's when it performs a search on what you've entered.  I expect your problem is not with Firefox, it's with your DNS resolver failing to resolve your `.vm` TLD.

- Double-check that you can ping the `.vm` hostnames you're trying to reach.
- Double-check that another browser (IE, Chrome, Opera) loads the hostnames properly.

If those don't work, fix the resolver problem, and Firefox should load your addresses.

Here's my test process: My home router is configured as a caching-DNS server and handles all local LAN lookups.  I've configured its `dnsmasq` to do local lookups from its /etc/hosts file.  My home server has a very basic webserver running, with an extra aliased network interface (eth0:0) on a static IP, but was given no additional configuration.

1. Added `x.x.x.x  project.vm` into the router's /etc/hosts,
2. Restarted the router's `dnsmasq` process, and
3. Checked that `ping hostname.vm` worked from all systems on the LAN.
4. Putting `project.vm` straight into Firefox's location bar goes straight to the website, no searching involved.